# Animating a UIView To A CGPoint

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview

I am wondering how I would go about animating a UIView's to a specific CGPoint.  The following is what I have so far (which doesn't work in it's current state):

```
#define MOVE_ANIMATION_DURATION_SECONDS 2

NSValue *pointValue = [[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point] retain];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:pointValue];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:MOVE_ANIMATION_DURATION_SECONDS];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#define MOVE_ANIMATION_DURATION_SECONDS 2

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:pointValue];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:MOVE_ANIMATION_DURATION_SECONDS];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];

CGRect frame = myUIViewObject.frame;
frame.origin = point;
myUIViewObject.frame = frame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: For some reason, the first time this runs, the animated view seems to go down on the y axis a little bit.  However, after this it works fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: I would check to see what the value of `point` is every time it is run - my guess is that `point` the first time is not what you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply fbrereton.  I fixed the problem and it works great now!

Answer (score 1):

After the begin, but before the commit, change the value on your UI View.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting 10.5 or above, you can use Core Animation via the animator proxy added to NSView. Try

```
[[someView animator] setFrame: someNewFrame];
```

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head (not yet had a chance to develop for the iPhone). I would imagine so.

Comment: The iPhone has a different view architecture than the Mac, so the animator proxy does not exist on the iPhone platform.